# Using PHP to execute terminal commands

Tags: php, shell, command-line, terminal

How can PHP be used to create a number of commands in the terminal? For example, if I want to change the permissions on a folder or a file, I might run

```
Sudo Chmod 777 FileName
```

from the command line. How could I do this with PHP?

Comment: I did a research but it seams i was searching for the wrong idea. that's why i posted the question.

Comment: Did you search for `execute command with php`??

Comment: no i was seaching for something similar to "run text file in terminal php" and the results was a bit confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `exec`, `system` etc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php

Obviously, if you are going to use `sudo` for root access stuff (not recommended) then you would need to either supply a password somehow or set the user which PHP is running as to not require a password.

It may be better to use an `SSH` call for this and supply the command to execute via that command.

To sum up, I really don't recommend using PHP (or any language for that matter) to run a series of commands which then uses `sudo`

Comment: @Lix - at least in this case the answer does expand with some do's and don'ts caveats.

Answer (score -2):

To give permission to folder or file in php use following line of code

```
chmod($file,0777);
```

this will change the permission of file or folder.