# Executing a command in terminal using php

Tags: java, php, exec, javac

I was trying to run an external command via php. Actually I want to compile a java file. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598561/using-php-to-execute-terminal-commands) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503633/executing-linux-commands-with-php). But unfortunately, in my case the java file doesn't compiling.

what is wrong in this code  ?

```
exec("javac Main.java");
```

but when I compiled it manually, and then execute the follwing command, it works fine.

```
exec("java Main");
```

Comment: Do you have tried absolute paths?

Comment: @timmy I'm running on windows. Is it really neccessary to give absolute path ? I mean in the server ?

Comment: couldn't hurt to try

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Tried, But still doesn't work :(

Comment: Your writing your code on Windows, but whats the OS on the Server? Do you use UNIX or Windows absolute paths? Is the JDK installed on your server?

Comment: @timmy and the thing is when running 'java Main' it works without the absolute path.

Comment: @timmy I'm running on WAMP server. Yep i've installed it.

Comment: Are there any error messages? (Think to enable `error_reporting(-1)`)

Comment: @timmy It returns 1 as the return value. I'm new to this and, I have no idea what it means.

Comment: I think 1 is an error code of `javac`... What does it return with [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)? The difference between [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) is, that `exec` does only return the last line of the output.